# Simplify a SQL query reducing no of joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query gives the correct results but i want the optimum query in terms of no of lines. Can this be more simplified?

```
SELECT 

[EventName]

  FROM [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblEvent] EVNT
  INNER JOIN
  [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblCountry] CTRY
  ON
  EVNT.CountryID = CTRY.CountryID
  INNER JOIN
  [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblContinent] CNT
  ON
  CNT.ContinentID = CTRY.ContinentID
  WHERE [ContinentName] 
   IN
  (
  SELECT CNAME FROM(

            SELECT TOP 3
            [ContinentName] AS CNAME,
            COUNT(EventName) AS EVENT_PER_CONTINENT
            FROM (
            SELECT [ContinentName],
            [EventName]
            --,SUM(COUNT(EventName) OVER(PARTITION BY [ContinentName] ORDER BY [ContinentName] ,[EventName]) AS COUNT

            FROM [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblContinent] CONTINENT
            INNER JOIN 
            [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblCountry] COUNTRY
            ON
            CONTINENT.ContinentID = COUNTRY.ContinentID
            INNER JOIN 
            [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblEvent] EVE
            ON 
            EVE.[CountryID] = COUNTRY.[CountryID]

            ) TABLE1

GROUP BY 
[ContinentName]

ORDER BY EVENT_PER_CONTINENT
ASC
) TABLE2

)
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: the problem is given in this URL as part of a SQL challenge > https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/sql/exercises/standard/subqueries/4228/

Comment: Using TOP without anny ORDER BY will return 100% non deterministic (random).. Only way to get pure 100% deterministic (fixed) is adding atleast one primary or unique column to the ORDER BY clause .. Which also can most likely help is adding a column where you know has unique values or has a high probability to have unique values like a `DATETIME(6)`  .. As SQL tables/results are defined to be **orderless** by the ANSI/iSO SQL standards.

Comment: I suggest you learn to write code using best practices FIRST, before you try accepting challenges. Using 3 part names decreases flexibility in moving between databases. You defined aliases for every table but never use them. You use square brackets around every name when not needed - which makes reading the code that much more difficult. Lastly - attend the course if you want the answer. And consider that you are violating the agreement you consented to with that website. Perhaps read the hints that were given in the exercise?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow the logic correctly, you want the events from the "top 3" continents by count.  Here is a simpler way to get this information:

```
SELECT EventName
FROM (SELECT ContinentID, EventName,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt, ContinentID) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT c.ContinentID, e.EventName
                   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ContinentID) AS cnt
            FROM [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblCountry] c INNER JOIN 
                 [WorldEvents].[dbo].[tblEvent] e
                 ON e.[CountryID] = c.CountryID
           ) ce
     ) ce
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```